# Loading GeoWebCache tiles into OpenLayers

Tags: tiles, geowebcache, openlayers

I have geotiff image that I want to show on a site locally (when there is no internet connection and browsing to localhost).

I've seen that OpenLayers 3 has XYZ layer but the format doesn't match the GeoWebCache output folder.

How can I view tiles locally from GeoWebCache... or is there free app which can generate XYZ tiles from Tiff ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using local tiles created in Geowebcache with OpenLayers](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76727/using-local-tiles-created-in-geowebcache-with-openlayers)

Comment: @MarkC - Your post is OL 2 related , I was asking on OL3.

Comment: Oops, sorry. The resolution in your answer is a good one anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve this in a different way.
I used this post http://www.aubrett.com/InformationTechnology/Geospatial/gdal2tilesTMSStructure.aspx to create TMS tiles and than using ol.source.XYZ to display them.